# How to make pattern after negative lookbehind greedy enough to match everything that follows it

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use a regular expression to match, for example, email addresses that to not appear inside a href property. So, given the following (partial) text

```
href="mailto:test@example.com"
whatever naked.email@example.net whatever
href="mailto:First Last <first.last@example.com>?Subject=SPAM"
```

I would like the regular expression to only alert me to the email address on the second line.

I have written a regular expression that I thought would do as required:

```regex
(?<!href=\"mailto:)(?:[ \w]*)?<?\b\w[\w\.]+@\w[\w\.]+
```

For the example text, it matches the second and third lines (namely, `whatever naked.email@example.net` and `irst Last <first.last@example.com`). It was not my intent that the third line would match. But obviously, the negative lookbehind causes the pattern following it to not include `F` in the match for that pattern, which causes the total pattern to match.

How can I modify the pattern so that it only matches the second line. I am interested both in specific solutions for the example problem of ‘naked’ email address matching as in insight into why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could first match what you don't want, and capture what you want to keep in a group.

In this case, you might use

```
href="[^"]*"|([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `href="[^"]*"` Match `href="` till the first occurrence of `"`
- `|` Or
- `([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)` Capture **group 1**, match an email like pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aii7EJ/1)